# React Native TextInput wont allow typing/text change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have a component that has a TextInput and 2 buttons. 1 button increments and the other decrements. I have an onChange and value on the TextInput and when the buttons are clicked the value changes(the text in the input increases or decreases), however typing the value via the TextInput, it doesn't work. It isn't allowing anything to be typed. Backspace won't even work after the increment/decrement buttons are clicked. Thought I'd put my code here to see if anyone could point out what I am missing. I think it has something to do with the `.toString()` on the value because when I remove that, I am able to type in the TextInput, but I need that `.toString()` there in order to do numbers and have the initial value as `null`.

This is the parent component:

```js
  measurementValue = (measurement) => {
    this.setState({ measurement });
  }

  updateMeasurement = () => {
    this.measurementValue(this.state.measurement);
  }

  decrement = () => {
    this.measurementValue(this.state.measurement - 1);
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.measurementValue(this.state.measurement + 1);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MeasurementControl
          updateMeasurement={this.updateMeasurement}
          decrement={this.decrement}
          increment={this.increment}
          measurement={this.state.measurement}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the child component:

```js
export class MeasurementControl extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      updateMeasurement,
      decrement,
      increment,
      measurement,
    } = this.props;
    const styles = getStyles();

    const value = measurement === null
    ? ''
    : measurement;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.input}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            keyboardType='numeric'
            placeholder='Enter #'
            onChangeText={updateMeasurement}
            value={value.toString()}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
          <Button
            buttonStyles={styles.decrementButton}
            textStyles={styles.decrementButtonText}
            onPress={decrement}
          >
            __
          </Button>
          <Button
            buttonStyles={styles.incrementButton}
            textStyles={styles.buttonText}
            onPress={increment}
          >
            +
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: does it work if you remove .toString() on value?

Comment: @floor in fact is does and I actually just edited my initial post with this finding.

Comment: remove the toString and change your value constant line to const value = measurement ? measurement  : null

Comment: @floor doing this I get an invalid prop type of number supplied to value, expected string and it also makes it so my increment and decrement buttons no longer work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `TextInput` have property called `onChangeText` this event will be triggered each time you write to the input

checkout my code

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.inputText}
    keyboardType='numeric'
    placeholder='Enter #'
    onChangeText={(text) => {

        if(text === ""){
            updateMeasurement(null);
            return;
        }

        if(isNaN(text))    //this will allow only number
            return;
        updateMeasurement(parseInt(text))}
    }
    value={value.toString()}
/>
```

---

```
updateMeasurement = (value) => {
    this.measurementValue(value);
}
```

Comment: This is the closest it has come to fully working. Now when I have a value in the input field and backspace so there is nothing, it reverts to `NaN` rather than it's initial value, which was `null`. Is there a way to have it display as blank again rather than `NaN` ?

Comment: Interesting. So hitting backspace now makes it a `0` rather than `NaN`, but is there a way to make it just blank so my placeholder text shows?

Comment: just make call `updateMeasurement` with empty string

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: I set it to return to null rather than an empty string because my value function above sets null to an empty string for the SQL table to read and that solved all my issues.

Comment: So another bug I ran into was that now when I have a negative number in the TextInput, it will not allow me to backspace to remove the negative value. Any idea why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658623/unable-to-type-in-formik-field Could you please have a look here? onChangeText does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

The part you are missing is to update the value on change

```
onChangeText={(text) => updateMeasurement(text)}


updateMeasurement = (text) => {
    this.measurementValue(text);
  }
```

Comment: is `text` a set value or can any word be used?

Comment: it can be anything

Comment: there you are getting the value from callback and passing to your function

Comment: So I implemented this and ran into an issue. When I type in a value of `5` and then use the increment button, it just tacks on `1` to the `5` (51111) rather than changing it to `6`.